# Where can I document things like "Business task" etc. for the Google data analysis Cyclistic case study?

Tags: data-analysis, coursera-api, capstone, google-data

Hey I have been stuck for a while on the Cyclistic case study. I have a bunch of questions. Where do you document the business task and all other text? What did you use to write down the business task and the documented changes and everything? I would really appreciate any help/advice.

Thank you for any help.

I think i might be limited to access to SQL and R unless I pay for them or something. I am just not even sure where to start with the project to even simply write the business task down and document any changes to the data.